# How to allow user content on the front page?

Tags: nodes

I am just struggling with my first site and a handful of friends helping to beta test.

Whenever admin posts there is an option to post to front page, but not for others.

I am not sure if I want the users to even see that option  -it might confuse the non-techy - but they do want to see their recent stuff on the front page.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the content type you want to be promoted you need to set the options on that content type to automatically be promoted to front page.

In Drupal7 find this under admin/structure/types pick one of the content types and choose "edit".  Under "Publishing Options" choose "Promoted to front page".

Answer (score 2):

The user has to be granted the permission to *Administer content* in order to publish it to the first page. You can find this under *admin/people/permissions* under the node subcategory. Check the box for the respective user.

Answer (score 1):

If you want fine grained control over this options have a look at [override_node_options](http://drupal.org/project/override_node_options)